# How to post metrics to InfluxDB with a simple HTML form?

Tags: html, forms, post, line-breaks, influxdb

I'm trying to send a `0` or a `1` to a database within my InfluxDB instance via a POST request from an HTML form. I've done this successfully lots of times through `curl`, but I can't make it work with a simple HTML form. Consider this HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- this file is called like http://my.influx.server/my_page_name.html -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>my simple html/influx sender</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="http://my.influx.server:8086/write?db=db_name" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
      <input name="data" type="hidden" value="my_measurement,tag_name=stuff value=1"/>
      <input type="submit" value="insert 1"/>
    </form>

    <form action="http://my.influx.server:8086/write?db=db_name" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
      <input name="data" type="hidden" value="my_measurement,tag_name=stuff value=0"/>
      <input type="submit" value="insert 0"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `curl` command for sending a `1`  would be like:

```
curl -i -XPOST 'http://my.influx.server:8086/write?db=mydb' --data-binary 'my_measurement,tag_name=stuff value=1'
```

So I tried to make a simple HTML form with just 2 buttons. The code above is the closest I could get to at least try to process the "line interface" syntax, however I'm getting either an error message or just no response and I don't get anything in my InfluxDB. The error message from the code above is:

```
unable to parse 'data=my_measurement,tag_name=stuff value=1\r': invalid number
```

If you have a close look at the end of the string, you see a `\r` that obviously gets added and I suspect that this breaks number parsing (I had something similar some time ago), but at least this seems to try to evaluate the line at all. However, I haven't found a way to remove or avoid the `\r`. **Has someone an idea how to achieve this?**

Also, please consider the following additional information:

- I want it really simple, just a small HTML file with possibly a bit of JavaScript code, but I'd really like to avoid using PHP, jQuery and such. Also, I'm trying to get used to HTML5 as you might notice, but this shouldn't be the problem.
- In this case, I don't need a timestamp for each key press, so instead of passing a timestamp I just use the current time. This is achieved by omitting the timestamp, so the string excluding the `\r` should be syntactically correct.
- I also looked for alternatives, however there was only the idea to use JSON and this seems not to be supported any more due to performance reasons (which I wouldn't expect in my case).
- The `curl` command uses the `--data-binary` parameter, but it seems I don't have anything like this in HTML. I'm aware of binary `enctype`s like `application/x-binary`, but they don't work, because they URL-encode the string and this won't pass the syntax check. The only `enctype` I found that worked at least close enough is `text/plain`.
- I'm also aware of form data not being sent, if the corresponding `<input>` element has no `name` attribute. Then I noticed that the `curl` string was built like `my_measurement,tag_name=stuff value=1`, possibly multiple such lines separated by `\n`, which is not like POST key-value-pairs as in `a=1&b=2` (i. e. there is no key, that would be the `name` attribute). Trying to trick it with `name="my_measurement,tag_name"` and `value="stuff value=1"` (which would resemble the original string) was not successful and I still couldn't figure out, which key is expected. I tried with `content`, `query` etc. and ended up using `data`. I kept this then because in the docs they talk about "data" and none of the keys made any difference, as long as one is provided. I suspect InfluxDB to just use the first POST variable ignoring the name, but I can't find any clear statement on this.
- I also tried several invisible `<input>` types like just `hidden` or a regular textbox hidden by style. This made no difference. Neither did visible elements.
- I also considered using AJAX, but I couldn't find anything useful about binary POSTs without key-value content. I even would cope with a page that only works e. g. for Firefox for now, so I don't need to switch between different AJAX object creation algorithms and such (yes, I know, jQuery helps, but see first point above).

---

**EDIT 1**: I tried to reproduce the error with `curl`:

```
curl -i -XPOST 'http://my.influx.server:8086/write?db=home' --data-binary 'my_measurement,tag_name=stuff value=1\r'
```

This led to the error message:

```
unable to parse 'my_measurement,tag_name=stuff value=1\\r': invalid number
```

with headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json
Request-Id: ...
X-Influxdb-Build: OSS
X-Influxdb-Error: unable to parse 'my_measurement,tag_name=stuff value=1\r': invalid number
X-Influxdb-Version: 1.7.9
X-Request-Id: ...
Date: ...
Content-Length: 78
```

I conclude:

- `\r` seems to be differently encoded in the error message (characters `\` and `r` instead of an actual carriage return), but in the header it's only `\r`, however it doesn't make a difference regarding the parsing error, so this is comparable.
- There is obviously no key name involved, so this is still different from my attempt above.

---

**EDIT 2**: I found out how to show the request headers from a call to `curl`. The command is:

```
curl -v -XPOST 'http://my.influx.server:8086/write?db=db_name' --data-binary 'my_measurement,tag_name=stuff value=1'
```

The relevant portion of the output of the command is:

```
> POST /write?db=db_name HTTP/1.1
> Host: my.influx.server:8086
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 37
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 37 out of 37 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
< Content-Type: application/json
< Request-Id: ...
< X-Influxdb-Build: OSS
< X-Influxdb-Version: 1.7.9
< X-Request-Id: ...
< Date: Sat, 25 Jan 2020 10:54:11 GMT
```

I conclude:

- Content type of the request invoked by `curl` with `--binary-data` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
- Unfortunately I couldn't achieve to see the actual request body, so I'll try again with some URL-encoded variants. However, `my_measurement,tag_name=stuff value=1` is 37 characters as in the request header, so I assume there is no key name like `data` involved. Currently, I get the same error message I had before I posted this question: `unable to parse 'data=my_measurement%2Ctag_name%3Dstuff+value%3D1': missing fields`
- The `\r` is gone, but I still can't send data without a key name and the whole string is invalid due to URL-encoding. **How to get rid of the URL-encoding?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution with JavaScript that worked. [This Mozilla doc page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript) was the key to a POST form without keys. My HTML page now looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- this file is called like http://my.influx.server/my_page_name.html -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>my simple html/influx sender</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1">
      <button>insert 1</button>
    </form>

    <form id="form0">
      <button>insert 0</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        function sendData(value)
        {
            const str = "my_measurement,tag_name=stuff value=" + value;
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
                alert("Success");
            });

            xhr.addEventListener("error", function(event) {
                alert("Error");
            });

            xhr.open("POST", "http://my.influx.server:8086/write?db=db_name");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            xhr.send(str);
        }

        const form0 = document.getElementById("form0");
        const form1 = document.getElementById("form1");

        form0.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            sendData(0);
        });
        form1.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            sendData(1);
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note the stripped-down form definitions: There are no `action`s, `method`s or `enctype`s any more, as they are set via JavaScript. Also, there is no regular `submit` element, instead it is a regular button, however I don't know if this is needed. I'll investigate that later.

The main part is in the script tag underneath the forms. A function `sendData` prepares an `XMLHttpRequest` object for `POST`ing a prepared string and invokes its `send` method. This function is used in the `submit` events of each form. Also, this function registers event handlers for successful and failed requests.

The lines below the `sendData` function identify the forms and register event listeners on their `submit` event. Each listener prevents its form from submitting in a regular fashion and invokes the appropriate `sendData` call instead, which will successfully insert values into InfluxDB.

Be aware, though, there is still no guarantee to detect every error. I tried to insert a string into an integer field, which failed, but I still got the "Success"-alert. I'm going to investigate that later.

So in total, I see this problem as sufficiently resolved for my purposes and I hope this helps anyone stumbling across it.

Answer (score 0):

This was a pretty useful post, I ran into this issue with the Sigfox backend and callbacks.

If you put an & at the end of the URL and use content type text/plain the \r\n issue is solved.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The line break issue was just a suspicious point that didn't lead anywhere for me. My actual problem was the key/value-thing, as it turned out. But still the "URL&" point is interesting. Could you tell me, where you found a hint at that?